# EF Core 3 GroupBy multiple columns Count Throws with extensions but linq works

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

Here is the one that throws full exception:

```
            var duplicateCountOriginal = _db.TableName
                                .GroupBy(g => new {g.ColumnA, g.ColumnB, g.ColumnC})
                                .Count(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

**Exception:** 
*System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Func`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer],Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Func`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer] Select[ValueBuffer,ValueBuffer](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer], System.Func`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer])' (Parameter 'arg1')*

But the same thing works when it is written as linq (I prefer extensions)

```
            var duplicateCount =
                    from a in _db.TableName
                    group a by new {a.ColumnA, a.ColumnB, a.ColumnC}
                    into g
                    where g.Count() > 1
                          select g.Key;
            duplicateCount.Count()
```

I am unable to understand why one works or the other doesn't. 
Also if I change the first one a little bit based on EF Core 3 changes like the following

```
            var duplicateCountOriginal = _db.TableName
                                .GroupBy(g => new {g.ColumnA, g.ColumnB, g.ColumnC})
                                .AsEnumerable()
                                .Count(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

I get the following **exception**:
*System.InvalidOperationException: Client projection contains reference to constant expression of 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IPropertyBase' which is being passed as argument to method 'TryReadValue'. This could potentially cause memory leak. Consider assigning this constant to local variable and using the variable in the query instead. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2103067 for more information.*

According to me, the link given by ms has no meaning to the whatever problem here is.

Please LMK if there is any logical explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no logical explanation. Just EF Core query translation is still far from perfect and have many defects/bugs/unhandled cases.

In this particular the problem is not the query syntax or method syntax (what you call extensions), but the lack of `Select` after `GroupBy`. If you rewrite the method syntax query similar to the one using query syntax, i.e. add `.Where`, `.Select` and then `Count`:

```
var duplicateCount = _db.TableName
    .GroupBy(g => new {g.ColumnA, g.ColumnB, g.ColumnC})
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .Count();
```

then it will be translated and executed successfully.

Comment: Although that's a not an equivalent query.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Just out of curiosity, why not?

Comment: My bad, It's the same.

Comment: I understand the point a little (still stupid from EF side), when groupby goes as the first item, you really cannot filter first and then group by. So if I want to first filter out some data (on sql side) and then group by on sql side again, it's not possible.  Based on this, you will have to group complete Table first and then play with your grouped result. (upside down) [not related to my or your example]

Comment: _db.T1.Where(s => s.A == "1" && s.B == "A")
                            .GroupBy(s => s.C)
                            .Select(s => new X
                            {
                                P1   = s.Count(q => q.M != "C"),
                                P2   = s.Count(q => q.M == "C"),
                                P3 = 0
                            }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

As an example. I understand it is getting little complex but counting those on client side is really absurd.

Comment: @SevDer You definitely can filter and then group by. The problems/defects of SQL translation are after group by, mainly for LINQ constricts which have no SQL equivalent. For instance, `Count` with condition as in your last example. But if you use conditional `Sum`, which has SQL equivalent, e.g. replace `P1 = s.Count(q => q.M != "C")` with `P1 = s.Sum(q => q.M != "C" ? 1 : 0)`, and similar for `P2`, you'll see the query fully translated and executed server side.